# How to obfuscate Flutter apps ios?

Tags: flutter, dart

please help me for the steps to obfuscate the code, step by step until it's finished?
and how do I see if my obfuscate code is successful or not.
Previously I tried running this command "flutter build ios --obfuscate --split-debug-info = /  / " but an error appears like this: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline ', why the error?

Answer (score 8):

The "obfuscate" function will split the debug-info for your Flutter app when building for the respective platform. for e.g., if your preparing to ship the version 2.0.1, then you'll get a folder named "2.0.1" which shall contain the .symbols files.

Now about how to get this done is by using this command `flutter build ios --obfuscate --split-debug-info=debug-info`

This will create a folder named `debug-info` in the root directory of your project and if you do have a new directory created in that after running the above command, then it means that the obfuscation was successful.

Comment: ok sir, I will try according to your instructions, but I have a few more questions I hope you are willing to answer.

Is it possible to run this command flutter build ios --obfuscate --split-debug-info = debug-info, can you upload it directly to the connect app store or do you have to run the flutter build ios again?

Is it possible to update my code after I obfuscate the code or is there a command to be able to do the update?

Comment: @Jsoon You'll have to do flutter build ios again. Actually this will strip the debug-info whenever you build for the specific platform(iOS here). After obfuscation, you cannot make changes to code. For that you'll again have to run the command since it is compiled. There is no option to update; hence you'll need to perform a build again

Comment: when i distribute the app through x-code it will build it again , what about the old obfuscation build on android studio ?

Comment: Wow, after reading your answer I realized my debug path was the cause of the error 